# How can I create my own menuconfig GUI?

Tags: linux, user-interface, makefile, desktop-application

I have a script in my mind where I first want to make a GUI for it. The GUI-Style should be the "menuconfig" (like from the Linux Kernel, Buildroot, etc.). I know one way is to ""copy paste"" the makefile of e.g. Buildroot, but I think to learn the basic rules this is may not be the best practice/easiest way.

I searched the Internet for some tutorials about writing that makefile but I couldn't find anything. Is it even an "easy job" or would be programming a GUI with Java Swing or QT even a easier solution to develop?

Does anyone have any good links about this topic?

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`dialog`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dialog_%28software%29) (`menuconfig` uses `lxdialog` which is based on `dialog`).

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for bringing me back to the right road, I already started programming ncurses!